# How to convert an object into a map using Java-8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Consider following object:

```
class Interval {
   final String name;
   final Date start;
   final Date end;
   final int intervalId;
}
```

I am provided with a list of intervals. I need to check it equals a given map.
eg:

```
boolean checkEqual(List<Interval> intervals, Map<Date, Date> startEnd) {


}
```

1. I want to use Java8 to convert list of intervals into a map of start/end dates and then compare with startEndMap

i.e.

```
boolean checkEqual(List<Interval> intervals, Map<Date, Date> startEnd) {
       Map<Date, Date> map = intervals.streams.filter ?? is there a way to do it ?
       return map.equals(startEnd)
}
```

How to do it ?

2. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Would you mind explaining your problem again please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector:

```
Map<Date, Date> result = intervals.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Interval::getStartDate, 
                             Interval::getEndDate));
```

Comment: how in the world did you understood it? :)

Comment: @Eugene my second skill set after programming is “mind reading” :)